# How to initialize weights in a pytorch model

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

I've got a fairly straight forward problem here. 
I've just finished re-configuring a network by replacing `nn.Upsample` with the `upConv` sequential container shown in the code below. I've verified that everything is lined up by running `summary(UNetPP, (3, 128, 128))` which runs with no issue.

```
def weights_init(m):
    classname = m.__class__.__name__
    if classname.find('Conv') != -1:
        m.weight.data.normal_(0.0, 0.02)
    elif classname.find('BatchNorm') != -1:
        m.weight.data.normal_(1.0, 0.02)
        m.bias.data.fill_(0)


class blockUNetPP(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_channels, middle_channels, out_channels):
        super().__init__()
        self.relu = nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, inplace=True)
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels, middle_channels, 3, padding=1)
        self.bn1 = nn.BatchNorm2d(middle_channels)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(middle_channels, out_channels, 3, padding=1)
        self.bn2 = nn.BatchNorm2d(out_channels)


    def forward(self, x):
        out = self.conv1(x)
        out = self.bn1(out)
        out = self.relu(out)

        out = self.conv2(out)
        out = self.bn2(out)
        out = self.relu(out)

        return out

class upConv(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_ch, out_ch):
        super().__init__()
        self.upc = nn.Sequential(
                                 nn.Upsample(scale_factor=2, mode='bilinear', align_corners=True),
                                 nn.Conv2d(in_ch, out_ch*2, 3, stride=1, padding=1),
                                 nn.BatchNorm2d(out_ch*2),
                                 nn.ReLU(inplace=True)
                                 )
    def forward(self, x):
        out = self.upc(x)
        return out
```

My issue is that when I try to start training the model I get the following issue:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "runTrain.py", line 90, in <module>
    netG.apply(weights_init)
  File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\envs\CFD\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 289, in apply
    module.apply(fn)
  File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\envs\CFD\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 290, in apply
    fn(self)
  File "D:\Thesis Models\Deep_learning_models\UNet\train\NetC.py", line 8, in weights_init
    m.weight.data.normal_(0.0, 0.02)
  File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\envs\CFD\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 594, in __getattr__
    type(self).__name__, name))
AttributeError: 'upConv' object has no attribute 'weight'
```

I've looked up  [solutions](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-to-initialize-weights-in-nn-sequential-container/8534) which suggest looping over container modules, but I'm already doing this with `weights_init(m)`. Could someone explain whats wrong with my current setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are deciding how to initialise the weight by checking that the class name includes *Conv* with `classname.find('Conv')`. Your class has the name *upConv*, which includes *Conv*, therefore you try to initialise its attribute `.weight`, but that doesn't exist.

Either rename your class or make the condition more strict, such as `classname.find('Conv2d')`. The strictest approach would be to check whether it's an instance of `nn.Conv2d`, instead of looking at the name of the class.

```py
def weights_init(m):
    if isinstance(m, nn.Conv2d):
        m.weight.data.normal_(0.0, 0.02)
    elif isinstance(m, nn.BatchNorm2d):
        m.weight.data.normal_(1.0, 0.02)
        m.bias.data.fill_(0)
```

Comment: Thanks, up and running now. I'm guessing is instance is a more robust method.